# jQuery bind on keypress not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to bind keypress and change of form values to an update function so the end user can see the effect of their updates real time. For some reason it is not firing at all.

HTML

```
<fieldset class="IOPS-field">
    <legend>IOPS/Bandwidth</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="bandwidth" value="IOPS-block" checked>IOPS at Block Size:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="IOPS" id="IOPS" value="500000" size="3"> at
                <select id="block-size">
                    <option value="4096" selected>4K</option>
                    <option value="8192">8K</option>
                    <option value="16384">16K</option>
                    <option value="32786">32K</option>
                    <option value="65536">64K</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="bandwidth" value="pure-bandwidth">Bandwidth (GBps):
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="bandwidth-entry" value="1953.125" id="bw" size="6">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

jQuery/javascript

```
function iops_bw_update(toUpdate) {
        var iops = parseInt($("#IOPS").val());
        var block = parseInt($("#block-size").val());
        var bw = parseFloat($("#bw").val());

        if (toUpdate == "BW") {
            $("#bw").val((iops*block)/1048576);
        }
        else {
            $("#IOPS").val((bw*1048576)/block);
        }
}

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#IOPS").bind("keypress", iops_bw_update("BW"));
    $("#bw").bind("keypress", iops_bw_update("IOPS"));
    $("#block-size").bind("change", iops_bw_update("BW"));
});
```

Comment: Please try use .on instead of bind, since bind is deprecated for lastest jquery versions

Comment: @Balder It doesn't say anything about it being deprecated at http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Sorry, you are right is live the one deprecated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function ref instead of passing the value of the function.

```
$("#IOPS").bind("keypress", your_function); // note: no () when no params need to be passed!
```

The correct way of binding a handler with params is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#IOPS").bind("keypress", function() {
        iops_bw_update("BW");
    });
    $("#bw").bind("keypress", function() {
        iops_bw_update("IOPS");
    });
    $("#block-size").bind("change", function() {
        iops_bw_update("BW");
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I'll accept in 5 minutes when I can.

Answer (score 0):

You have not bound a function. You have called it.

try like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#IOPS").bind("keypress", iops_bw_update);
    $("#bw").bind("keypress", iops_bw_update);
    $("#block-size").bind("change", iops_bw_update);
});
```

Comment: I updated the code to envoke the functions directly, bind wasn't giving me the behavior I was looking for. Still not firing.

Comment: Again you are making same mistake. While binding you are calling function by using parenthesis. Like this : `$("#IOPS").keypress(iops_bw_update);`

Comment: Inside iops_bw_update you can use this.id to check which input field has fired the function.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript () means calling the function. If you want to bind the function you have to put only the function name, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#IOPS").keypress(iops_bw_update);
    $("#bw").keypress(iops_bw_update);
    $("#block-size").change(iops_bw_update);
});
```

you don't need to put the complete function in the binding. Only the name without the ().